# Rule based Part of Speech parsing dilemma

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I'm currently trying to build a sentence parser that extracts unknown parts of speech. Its a bit abstract but my methodology is basically creating a set of grammatical rules that the function can use to parse the text.

I'm using Spacy's PoS tagger right now just to extract the pos tags from an example sentence. I know Spacy also has a dependency parser but from what I've read on the documentation its used for matching a **known** phrase.

So my question is this:

By creating a set of grammatical rules, whats the best way to extract an **unknown** target word from a string based off of those rules?

For example:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

Example = "I really hate all people who are green, I wish they would go back home"
ex_string = Example.split()
doc = nlp(Example)
pos_tagged_context = [token.tag_ for token in doc]
Word_Dict = {}
```

The first rule in this case would be the PoS tag list of `pos_tagged_context` which matches the sentence structure of `ex_string`

```
['PRP', 'RB', 'VBP', 'DT', 'NNS', 'WP', 'VBP', 'JJ', ',', 'PRP', 'VBP', 'PRP', 'MD', 'VB', 'RB', 'RB']
```

Two problems arise from this though, the easier one being that when printing `Word_Dict` several PoS tags are lost:

```
{'I': ',', 'really': 'RB', 'hate': 'VBP', 'all': 'DT', 'people': 'NNS', 'who': 'WP', 'are': 'VBP', 'green,': 'JJ', 'wish': 'PRP', 'they': 'VBP', 'would': 'PRP', 'go': 'MD', 'back': 'VB', 'home': 'RB'}
```

The second problem is more abstract, since the structure of a "negative" sentence is inherently relative is there a good "general form" when creating these rules?

An ideal output would use the structure of the sentence and identify the target word within it, in this case "green".

Let me know if the question is too abstract or needs more clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following code:

```
import spacy


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

examples = ["I really dislike endives because they taste bitter.", "I like Fridays but I hate Mondays."]

negativeVerbs = ['hate', 'dislike'] 

for e in examples:
    doc = nlp(e)   
    candidateVerbs = [t for t in doc if (t.text in negativeVerbs and t.pos_ == 'VERB')]
    if candidateVerbs:
        candidateVerb = candidateVerbs[0]

        #print(candidateVerbs)
        print(e)
        print([c.text for c in candidateVerb.children if c.dep_ == 'dobj'])
```

ouput:

> I really dislike endives because they taste bitter.

```
['endives']
```

> I like Fridays but I hate Mondays.

```
['Mondays']
```

Comment: This is excellent, the only caveat being is that your list `negativeVerbs` is provided, I'm trying to find negative words (hate speech in this case) without knowing what the actually word is. So the context around the word is what I'm trying to establish. So tldr I'm looking for unknown words but looking at the whole sentance